# How can I show my enterprise's history with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

:)

I would like to create something like that :
[image]

I'm working on Wordpress and my theme is Jupiter.

Have an idea ?

Comment: These elements are called vertical timelines, if your theme does not support it you've got to build it yourselfe via shortcode/plugin. Maybe you can check this out https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/ or someone made a plugin already ;)

Comment: Vertical timeline ? I don't have any element called like that .. sh*t ^^ Ok I'll look your link, thank you :)